# line parallel to plane, but not on plane.

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, analytic-geometry

I need to find a plane that goes through the points $A=(2,0,2)$ and $B=(4,1,0)$, that is parallel to the line?

$$r(t) = (0,3,-2) + t\langle1,-1,1\rangle$$

or if you want it in parametric equations:

$$x = t, \ y = 3 - t, \ z = t - 2.$$

How do I find a plane that goes through two points? and how do I decide if it is parallel to the line?

Comment: Every plane is uniquely defined by a point in this plane and two nonparallel directions. You have a point ($A$) and one of directions ($(1,-1,1)$, since the plane is parallel to the line). You can take $\overline{AB}=(2,1,-2)$ as a second direction.

Comment: What is the approach when the line in the plane and the line parallel to the plane are both parallel?

Answer (score 2):

Notice that if the plane is parallel to L, then the vector normal to the plane is then perpendicular to the line. Find the/ (a) vector normal to the plane, then you have two points in the plane, and you're done.

And there are infinitely-many planes that go through any two given points; there are infinitely-many planes that even go through a given line. Once you're given a vector normal to the plane, and two points in the plane, you're done ( although, given two points, you can find N using their cross-product. )

If the line lies in the plane, you can translate the plane to avoid containing the line.

Comment: I dont understand what to do...

To find a normal vector, I guess I could have done a cross product on two vectors, but I only have one vector. 

I dont know how to make two points into a vector and even if I did, then I have one vector in the plane (made from the points) and another one that is not in the plane... should I still make a cross product between them?

Comment: You can use the fact that a vector normal to the plane would then be perpendicular to the line L. So use L to find a vector perpendicular to the line, and use it as the vector normal to the plane; then the plane may contain the line. If so, you can translate the plane so that it avoids the line.

Comment: I dont get it, can you show a example? I know that in general a line ax+by=c1 has a perpendicular −bx+ay=c2. But I dont know how to translate that in 3d. and even if I did, I dont know how to make a plane out of such a line and two points.

Comment: I don't want to take you too far afield, so , just to know: have you seen orthogonal complements in your class? The orthogonal complement of a vector  v is the collection of all vectors orthogonal to v. If you have not seen this, could you tell me what related material have you seen?

Answer (score 0):

The plane is parallel to both the line $AB$ and to the given line, so it is normal to the cross product of vectors along these lines. Knowing the normal and a point (let $A$), finding the equation of the plane is straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answers already given, you can consider that
if the line is parallel to the plane, you can "transport" the vector defining the line onto the plane, in particular you can "fix" it on $B$ (or on $A$) and determine a third point $C=(4,1,0)+(1,-1,1)=(5,0,1)$